# RewriteEngine for SSL redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Relevant setion of my .htaccess pasted below. Works great except... If I type https://mydomain/abc.php, it does not redirect to https://mydomain/www/abc.php. On the other hand, if I type http://mydomain/abc.php, it correctly redirects to https://mydomain/www/abc.php. I want both to redirect to https://mydomain/www/abc.php. Your help with the necessary adjustment to the regex (a blindspot of mine) would be greatly appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/www%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache, using the .htaccess file for redirection has been deprecated. (You can take a look [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect). They recommend using the `Redirect` directive directly inside your main server file. You can to that like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/www/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/www/
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

In the case where you are not able to access directly to the server, you can do this in your .htaccess file like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/ www
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{HTTP_HOST}%/www/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{HTTP_HOST}%/www/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have root access on this server, so .htaccess is my only option.

Comment: The rule without `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` can cause a redirect loop since it would redirect `https` urls back to `https` . RewriteCond is important in this case.

Comment: Many thanks. Works perfectly. Obvious now I see it. Blinded by regex fear!